# Height 100% not working for DIV tag in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height

I have the following code that I am using to display a search tool with a scrolling results section. In IE the code works fine:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html style="background:black;height:100%;width:100%;">
    <head>
      <title>Report</title> 
    </head>
    <body style="background:black;">
      <table HEIGHT="100%" WIDTH="100%" style="background:red;">
      <tr>
      <td>
        Search Area  
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td HEIGHT="100%" WIDTH="100%" style="background:orange;">
        <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100%;">
          <table style="width:100px;height:1000px;">
          <tr>
          <td style="background:white;">
            Results Area
          </td>
          </tr>
          </table>
        </div>      
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But when I set the meta tag to use IE8 formatting by adding:

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
```

The bottom DIV tag expands beyond the page. I have tried a number of options though and can't find a way around it without actually specifying a height for the values. Which will not work as I want the page to take up 100% of the screen no matter the size of the browser window.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This metatag enables correct CSS rendering, and in CSS – by design – `height:100%` [basically doesn't work](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property).

You need to give specific height to *every* single ancestor of the element, including `<body>`, `<table>`, `<tr>` and even `<tbody>` element that's automatically inserted by the parser.

Anyway, this layout can be achieved in easier way:

```
.topBanner {
    position:absolute; position:fixed; 
    height:2em; 
    top:0; left:0; width:100%;
}
body {padding-top: 2em}
```

this will degrade nicely in IE6, and unlike `overflow`, will work properly in Mobile Safari.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Removing the DOCTYPE declaration will make height="100%" work but it puts the browser in quirks mode though, which is not desirable.

Generally speaking using tables for layout is discouraged, you should use CSS instead.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/rf649/7/

**HTML**

```
<div id="search">Search Area</div>
<div id="results">Results Area</div>
```

**CSS:**
   ​

```
#search {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
}
#results{
    background-color: orange;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
​
```

Comment: Removing the doctype can push your page into quirksmode which will most likely cause more problems than it fixes.

Comment: @JoelPotter - I agree, you are right, I have updated the answer

Comment: This CSS also has its issues in relation to cross-browser compatibility (though probably not as bad as removing the DOCTYPE), as IE6 doesn't properly handle `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set all margins and paddings for the parent elements to zero in order to get what you want.

**Update:** Sorry, didn't understand the problem at once. Ben's hint should be the better one I assume. :)

**Update 2:** Oops, since Ben has deleted his answer my first update doesn't make any sense. Try setting the body's height to 100%, that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about cross browser CSS is not that big so it might not be the best solution, but it's a solution.

As far as I've seen, you always have to set the height/width of the container that you want to overflow, so you need to set them.

To deal with the resolution I would suggest you to add a jQuery script at the onReady event that dynamically would fix the height and width making the overflow work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem like you and finally the solution was to modificate a CSS line entry that had an `!important` modificator for a fixed height declaration. In the HTML code the class (defined in CSS) had the `height` assigned to `100%`, but the CSS applied the `!important` during the style loading.